# How to enlarge image from thumbnail in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image

On my website there is a list of small thumbnails ("t1.jpg", "t2.jpg", "t3.jpg",...) and I want to create code that in centered dialog box will show a full-size version of the image. How to do this?

For example when I click on t1.jpg I want to see in centered box a big1.jpg image. Dynamically. I don't want to load all images when the page is loading. It must be good performance for that.

Anyone can give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd advise you to post your (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery. Then we can see how we might be able to help. Posting a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo would also help out a lot.

Comment: You could also just use something like jQuery Lightbox if you don't need to write all the code yourself.

Comment: I don't have a code. Just a list of HTML images. I don't need you to write me all code lines. Just an advice - what library use or method.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a really simple approach - a simplified version of [**Darkbox Gallery**](https://github.com/rokobuljan/Darkbox-Gallery):

Basically you store the large image `src` in a `data-pop` attribute.
The popup is called when such `data-pop` element is clicked.
The CSS is really straightforward and even the jQuery should not be much complicated - beside the part that calculates the current window size in order to define should the popup's background image be CSS3 `contain` or `auto` - where *"auto"* is used for smaller images (so they don't scale):

```js
/* POP BOX */
;(function() {

  var $pop = $("#pop");

  $(document).on("click", "[data-pop]", function() {

    var popSrc= $(this).data("pop"),
        docW= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
        docH= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

    $pop.addClass("visible loading").css({backgroundImage:"none"});

    $("<img/>").on("load", function() {
      var bigger = (this.width > docW || this.height > docH)
      $pop.removeClass("loading").css({
        backgroundSize: bigger ? "contain" : "auto",
        backgroundImage: "url(" + this.src + ")"
      });
    }).attr("src", popSrc);

  });

  $("#popClose").on("click", function() {
    $pop.removeClass("visible loading");
  });

}());
```

```css
/* 
POP BOX 
*/
#pop {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) none no-repeat 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  left: 24px;
  top: 24px;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#pop.loading:after {
  content: "Loading...";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 44%;
}

#pop.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#popClose {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!-- POP BOX -->
<div id="pop"><a id="popClose">&times;</a></div>

<!-- USE EXAMPLE -->
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0bf" data-pop="http://placehold.it/860x590/0bf" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f0b" data-pop="http://placehold.it/590x860/f0b" alt="" />



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several jQuery lightbox scripts that will help you do this.

Here is a list of some of the best: http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Like a jquery lightbox?

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts

The images load in a modal when the image thumbnail is clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Lightbox. There's  jQuery plugin for it. Check out the "How to Use" tab on the official site:
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

I think [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) is a good choice.
They have an example of the feature you want in this page.