# Jquery enlarge image from thumbnail in jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate an example of an jquery plugin that enlarges image from thumbnail at my desktop and the problem is , the image doesn't enlarge from the thumbnail whenever I click on it

Here is the original source of the jquery demo that enlarges image from thumbnail that i'm trying to replicate
[How to enlarge image from thumbnail in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575061/how-to-enlarge-image-from-thumbnail-in-jquery)

This is his working demo http://jsbin.com/egevij/3/edit

The problem is in my HTML .Can someone please point where I'm going wrong?

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/forms.css">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo by roXon</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="jQ_popup_window">
<div id="jQ_popup" class="shadow radius">
    <div id="jQ_popup_close"></div> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="trouble.js"></script>
</div>
</div>




<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/cf5" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/cf5" alt="" />

<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/fof" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/fof" alt="" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

forms.css CSS

**CSS:**

```
/* === POPUP WINDOW === */
#jQ_popup_window{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -9000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:999999;
}
#jQ_popup {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #BDB9B8;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px; /* SET HERE DESIRED W .*/
}
#jQ_popup_close {
    background:#fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999999;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
            border-radius:30px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
#jQ_popup_close:hover{
    background:#f00;    
}
/* #POPUP WINDOW */
```

jQuery:

```
   // POPUP WINDOW:
   var scrT = $(window).scrollTop();
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      scrT = $(window).scrollTop(); 
   });

   // GET and use WINDOW HEIGHT //
    $.getDocHeight = function(){
        var D = document;
        return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
    };  


    // POPUP WINDOW (lightbox for video and other)  
    // GET WINDOW SCROLLtop OFFSET
$('[data-full]').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#jQ_popup').css({
        top: scrT+15
    }).find('img').remove();
    $('#jQ_popup_window').height($.getDocHeight).fadeTo(0,0).css({
        marginLeft:0
    }).fadeTo(600,1);

    var imgToLoad = $(this).data('full');
  $('<img>', {src:imgToLoad, width:'100%'}).appendTo('#jQ_popup');


});
// close popup
$('#jQ_popup_close, #jQ_popup_window').on('click', function(){      
    $('#jQ_popup_window').fadeTo(600,0,function(){
        $(this).hide();         
    });
});
$('#jQ_popup').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
// end POPUP WINDOW
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or bin with this code running in it?

Comment: @NuclearGhost I had difficulty implementing on fiddle before but , if you take a look at the example here http://jsbin.com/egevij/3/edit , all I did was cut the javascript and place it on the area where it said --jquery -- . I don't understand why it won't work

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code from here into a bin and it works fine for me... http://jsbin.com/onimoc/1/edit

Comment: @NuclearGhost if you Remove the <script type = "text/javascript" src ="trouble.js"></script> . It will still work . I think jsbin will automatically read the javascript if you see in the real demo. jsbin.com/egevij/3/edit . The guy doesn't show where he insert the javascript code at his html

Comment: Yes jsbin will automatically read in that javascript.  So your javasciprt lives in a file called trouble.js that lives in the same directory as your html page?

Comment: @NuclearGhost Yep . Try it on your desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is simply moving the import of the JavaScript file.  It should be placed at the end after your two `<img>` tags.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/cf5" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/cf5" alt="" />

<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/fof" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/fof" alt="" /> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="trouble.js"></script>
```

It's standard practice to load your javascript files either last in the head or last in the body.  Putting script tags inside of other html tags such as `<div>` as you have done is not normal but I've never seen it have ill effects like this before.

Comment: @Jacob I would recommend reading about including external script files.  I don't recommend including it in both locations