# modifying an enlargement image from thumbnail script to dynamically display image based on their size property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify this simple js script that enlarges the image from thumbnail whenever it is clicked. The problem is , the enlarged image is displayed according to an define fixed width. I want  the enlarged image displayed according to it's size property.For example of an image size is 200 width and 300 height , I want that image to be display according to that size instead of an fixed 300 height and width.

I'm been trying solutions such as removing the width but instead the image is enlarged to the full screen size.

How can I modify this script so the enlarged image is displayed according to it's original size property.

The script belongs to roXon and I give full credit to him
[How to enlarge image from thumbnail in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575061/how-to-enlarge-image-from-thumbnail-in-jquery)

This is the jquery http://jsbin.com/egevij/3/edit

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/forms.css">

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo by roXon</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="jQ_popup_window">
<div id="jQ_popup" class="shadow radius">
    <div id="jQ_popup_close"></div> 

</div>
</div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/cf5" data-full="1.jpg" alt="" />

  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/fof" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/fof" alt="" /> 
  <script type = "text/javascript" src ="trouble.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
   // POPUP WINDOW:
   var scrT = $(window).scrollTop();
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      scrT = $(window).scrollTop(); 
   });

   // GET and use WINDOW HEIGHT //
    $.getDocHeight = function(){
        var D = document;
        return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
    };  


    // POPUP WINDOW (lightbox for video and other)  
    // GET WINDOW SCROLLtop OFFSET
$('[data-full]').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#jQ_popup').css({
        top: scrT+15
    }).find('img').remove();
    $('#jQ_popup_window').height($.getDocHeight).fadeTo(0,0).css({
        marginLeft:0
    }).fadeTo(600,1);

    var imgToLoad = $(this).data('full');
  $('<img>', {src:imgToLoad, width:'100%'}).appendTo('#jQ_popup');


});
// close popup
$('#jQ_popup_close, #jQ_popup_window').on('click', function(){      
    $('#jQ_popup_window').fadeTo(600,0,function(){
        $(this).hide();         
    });
});
$('#jQ_popup').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
// end POPUP WINDOW
```

**CSS:**

```
/* === POPUP WINDOW === */
#jQ_popup_window{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -9000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:999999;
}
#jQ_popup {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #BDB9B8;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px; /* SET HERE DESIRED W .*/
}
#jQ_popup_close {
    background:#fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999999;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
            border-radius:30px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
#jQ_popup_close:hover{
    background:#f00;    
}
/* #POPUP WINDOW */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should probably work

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/fof" data-full="http://placehold.it/860x590/fof" data-width="860px" data-height="590px" alt="" />

$('<img>', {src:imgToLoad, width: $(this).data('width'),height: $(this).data('height')}).appendTo('#jQ_popup');
```

or this one takes the size from the path /860x590/

```
var dimensions=$(this).data('full').match(/(\d+)x(\d+)/);
$('<img>', {src:imgToLoad, width: dimensions[1]+'px',height: dimensions[2]+'px'}).appendTo('#jQ_popup');
```

Comment: what has got a border? the image?

Comment: img{border-style: none;} in your css

Comment: oh ok glad you got it sorted :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I can't get it to be in the right place, are you sure its not something to do with running it in jsbin?

Comment: you can still do it the first way the same just using $(this).data('width') in place of dimensions[1]

Comment: the main thing is to add  $('#jQ_popup').css({width:$(this).data('width')+'px'});