# making a slideshow, what jQuery method to use to enlarge a slide thumbnail when clicked on?

Tags: jquery

I am making a slideshow.  I have a bunch of slides (bottom of page) below the canvas, but I can't find the right jQuery to call.  What jQuery method could I use instead of .replaceWith() to replace a canvas with a larger version of it's thumbnail when clicked on.

See my codepen

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 

  $( ".text" ).click(function() {
    $( ".cloneditems" ).append( "<p>Click to EDIT</p>" );
    $(".cloneditems > p").draggable();
    $(".cloneditems > p").attr("contenteditable", true);
  });


  $( ".addslide" ).click(function() {
   alert("yay you clicked me");
   $( ".replaceme" ).replaceWith( $( "h1" ) );
   $(".singleslide").clone().insertAfter(this);
  });
  

 
});
```

Comment: my codepen https://codepen.io/monkeycrane2010/pen/XWNJEXy

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: I'll give this a try @epascarello

Comment: I searched google again, and found this stackOverflow article that looks closer to my answer I'm looking for "How to enlarge image from thumbnail in jQuery?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575061/how-to-enlarge-image-from-thumbnail-in-jquery